# How to build docker image with spring boot app?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, dockerfile, docker-maven-plugin

I am trying to build up image with my app but i can't do it correctly. How to create dockerfile if i am using Spring Boot and Java 11? After create dockerfile

```
 mvnw spring-boot:build-image
```

is all i need to do?

Comment: Yes, what so you want to know

Comment: What should contain dockerfile?

Comment: Your don't need a Dockerfile. Spring Boot uses Buildpacks